# Show full name in annotation bar

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

This might be a stupid question, but since my co-worker and I have the same last name the annotation bar is quite confusing. You can see the full name of the person who pushed the code to the repository when you hover over the line, but is there a way to show either only the first name or the full name in this view?

Comment: I share your pain, I have some colleagues with the same surname

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Right click the annotation gutter, select `View | Names | First Name` or `View | Names | Full Name` from the menu.

[image: Visual explanation about how to change commit author in IntelliJ]

Comment: this is why I like intellij, so many ways to customize